# Java MVC: How to set changed the main model class properly when another class changed

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, awt, mouseevent

I am writing a program where some elements need to be selected by clicking on them. I am doing this using the MVC principle. I have the following Model class

```
public class Model extends Observable {
    public Model() {
        ....
    }

    public void changeSomething() {
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }
}
```

So basically, whenever I changed something in the model, it updates the view accordingly. 
Now, I have a class `Selecter`, which is simply and extension of `MouseAdapter`, with some added functions to check the input. Preferably, I want to keep track of the currently selected object within the `Selecter` class, rather then in `Model`, just to keep it all seperate. But if I want to change the color of the selected object when that object has been selected, I need to call `model.setChanged();` and `model.notifyObservers();` (where`model` is a `Model` object passed through), which I really dislike.
Is there a proper way to this, without violating MVC?

Comment: Probably you need `JToggleButton` or `JCheckBox` instead of your `Selecter`?

Comment: Well, it's not a button. It is a custom object displayed as a rectangle. I got the clicking and selecting working already. I just need an elegant way to update the view classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first, what I miss in your code is the information about the change. `setChanged()` without parameters looks ugly. I would suggest the following change for your model class:

```
public class SelecterModel {
    public static final String SELECTED_PROPERTY = "selected";
    private final PropertyChangeSupport support = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private boolean selected;

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public boolean setSelected(boolena selected) {
        boolean old = this.selected;
        this.selected = selected;
        support.firePropertyChange(SELECTED_PROPERTY, old, selected);
    }

    public void addSelectionChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener pcl) {
        support.addPropertyChangeListener(SELECTED_PROPERTY, pcl);
    }

    public void removeSelectionChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener pcl) {
        support.removePropertyChangeListener(SELECTED_PROPERTY, pcl);
    }
}
```

Now your mouse controller on mouse click calls the method of model:

```
model.setSelected(!model.isSelected());
```

The view code should register a listener to be notified, when controller is changed:

```
model.addSelectionChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        setBackground(Boolean.TRUE == evt.getNewValue()? Color.GREEN : Color.YELLOW);
        // probably some another changes
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That's both clever and clear. About the setChanged(), this is how we've been tought that in class, and I haven't bothered to look up any information about it. So also thanks for making me do!